# Как создать мультиязычный сайт с разным количеством записей?

Tags: wordpress-плагины

Очень удобно вести на одном домене контент на двух языках. однако возникла такая проблема, что, указано почти в любом плагине, можно скрыть контент если для данной страницы или записи нет перевода. однако я все равно вижу в английской части посты на русском. как их скрыть в итоге? потому что не все записи имеют смысл перевода на оба языка.
или в таком случаи стоит создавать 2 разных сайта?

---

Дополнено:
я поняла почему не скрываются на русском записи. потому что изначально плагин дублирует записи на два языка. если удалить содержимое в одном из языков, тогда запись не отображается на другом языке. но если у меня +100 записей. так каждую корректировать .....
как это исправить?

Comment: С WPML такой проблемы нет.

Comment: он платный, мне нужен более доступный вариант для непубличного блога

Answer (score 0):

А какие плагины Вы пробовали?

Я использовал [qTranslate X](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) (пока его не забросили) и [WP Multilang](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/). Такой проблемы не замечал. Возможно, не все галочки поставили в настройках?
Если проблема сохраняется, то попробуйте обратиться на форум поддержки плагина, который используете.

Comment: именно их и использовала и галочки ставила. может конечно проблема в том что он берут инфу из настроек браузера, русский язык, потому что записи видно. но собственно  qTranslate X уже 2 года без обновлений почти что 3. а вот с WP Multilang сайт вообще перестал работать и почему то указывать стал на частный редирект, интересно откуда и куда

Comment: я поняла почему не скрываются на русском записи. потому что изначально на обоих языках плагин дублирует записи на два языка. если удалить запись, тогда ее нет на английском. но если у меня 100 записей. так каждую корректировать не комильфо.....